# IOexception: The account used is a computer account

Tags: c#, asp.net

My website throws the following exception:

> IOException: The account used is a computer account. Use your global user account or local user account to access this server

How can I fix that?

Comment: Have you tried under different application pool identities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this running under a shared hosting provider? That seems likely, based on other people's [similar experiences](http://n2cms.codeplex.com/discussions/216081). Alternatively, you may not be [mapping virtual to physical paths](http://forums.asp.net/t/1273264.aspx) correctly.

Can you provide the full stack trace of the exception?